# Double integral - area between two parabola

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have to calculate the area between parabolae $y^2=10x+25$ and $y^2=-6x+9$

However I have not been able to do so. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

What I tried to do:

**1.**

I tried splitting the area at x=-1. I took that $x\in[-\frac{5}{2}, -1]$ for the first area, and $y \in [-\sqrt{10x+25}, \sqrt{10x+25}]$ and $x\in[-1, \frac{5}{2}]$ and $y \in [-\sqrt{-6x+9}, \sqrt{6x+9}]$. For the first area I get that it's $2\sqrt{15}$, but the second area can't be calculated that simply. WolframAlpha returns a complex value.

**Note**: I may have made a mistake with the boundaries. I didn't know how to proceed because, if we go from bottom to top to find the boundaries for $y$, we find that it's bounded by the "same" function (parabola).

**2.**

Next, I tried splitting the area at y=0. That way, I would have $ y \in [-\sqrt{15},0]$ for the first part, and $ y\in [0, \sqrt{15}]$ for the second part.

However, here I have problems expressing $x$ in terms of $y$.  If I go from left to right for the area below the x axis, I encounter the part of the red parabola that is below the x axis, but **I don't know how to express it.**. The most I can get is $x=\frac{y^2-25}{10}$ and that's the whole parabola, not the lower half!

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

The intersection points of the parabolas are the points $\left(-1,\pm\sqrt{15}\right)$.

So, the area is$$\int_{-\sqrt{15}}^{\sqrt{15}}\color{blue}{\frac{9-y^2}6}-\color{red}{\frac{y^2-25}{10}}\,\mathrm dy=16\sqrt{\frac53}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can express $x$ in terms of $y$ and that gives bounds of $x$ as,

$\dfrac{y^2-25}{10} \leq x \leq \dfrac{9-y^2}{6}$

And at intersection of both curves, $y^2 = 15 \implies y = \pm \sqrt{15}$

So the integral to find area can be written as,

$\displaystyle \int_{-\sqrt{15}}^{\sqrt{15}} \int_{(y^2-25)/10}^{(9-y^2)/6} dx \ dy $

If you go in the order $dy \ dx$, you will have to split the integral into two, which is what you first did.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems logical, but here's why I didn't do it: In some exercises, I have seen that the solutions **separate** the lower and upper half of the parabola as $y=\pm \sqrt{f(x)}$. I thought I should do so here, too, because we integrate both above and below the x axis.

Sorry I am a newbie to this but I want to learn!

Comment: Understood but if you split it into two, below and above x-axis, you will still keep the bounds of $x$ same. Only that the limits of $y$ will be $-\sqrt{15}$ to $0$ and then from $0$ to $\sqrt{15}$. The area below $x$ axis and above is the same in this case as x-axis is the axis of both parabola.

Comment: @THE_CRANIUM You also mentioned that when you were doing it in the order $dx \ dy$, you had an issue in the domain $x\in[-1, \frac{5}{2}]$. That is because the domain is $x\in[-1, \frac{3}{2}]$ for the second integral.

Comment: So, I've got my boundaries wrong it seems. Thanks for correcting me

also one last question: Am I right if I say that we do not need to split the integral if we do it in the order $dxdy$ **because** the small horizontal stripes (dx) in  the area are **always** bound between the two same curves?

Comment: @THE_CRANIUM That is absolutely correct! I will give link to an answer of mine that explains it further.

Comment: @THE_CRANIUM See if this helps. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4174377/double-integrals-when-do-i-need-to-split-the-area-of-integration/4174408?noredirect=1#comment8654092_4174408

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Both your approaches are, conceptually correct. However there are mistakes.

For $1$:
The second area can definitely be calculated, quite easily. But your limits are incorrect. The upper limit wouldn't be $\frac 52$, rather it'd be $\frac 32$. It gives:
$$I=2\int_{-1}^{\frac 32} \sqrt {9-6x}\ dx$$ which I'm sure you can finish.

For $2$:
You should observe that if $y^2=-6x_1+9$ and $y^2=10 x_2+25$ are the two conics, then upon choosing $y$-axis as base, we get area given by the integral:
$$A=\int_{-\sqrt 15}^{\sqrt 15} (x_2-x_1)\ dy$$
Now both $x_1, x_2$ can be represented in terms of $y$, hence $A$ can be evaluated.